# MySQL batch load of multiple tables with auto-incremented fields as foreign keys

Tags: mysql

Consider the following contrived example where a **FOREST** contains **TREE**(s) and **TREE**(s) have **BRANCH**(es).  Additionally **FLOCK**(s) contain **BIRD**(s) and **BIRD**(s) may or may not be on a **BRANCH**.

```
CREATE TABLE 'FOREST' (
forest_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
'name'    VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
...
)

CREATE TABLE 'TREE' (
'tree_id'    INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
'forest_id'  INT(11) NOT NULL ,
'tree_loc_x' INT NOT NULL,
'tree_loc_y' INT NOT NULL,
...
CONSTRAINT 'fk_tree_forest'
    FOREIGN KEY ('forest_id' )
    REFERENCES `FOREST` ('forest_id' )
)

CREATE TABLE 'BRANCH' (
'branch_id' INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
'tree_id'   INT(11) NOT NULL,
'br_loc_x'  INT NOT NULL,
'br_loc_y'  INT NOT NULL,
'br_loc_z'  INT NOT NULL,
...
CONSTRAINT 'fk_branch_tree'
   FOREIGN KEY ('tree_id' )
   REFERENCES `TREE` ('tree_id' )
)

CREATE  TABLE 'FLOCK' (
  'flock_id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  'name'     VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL
...
)

CREATE  TABLE 'BIRD' (
  'bird_id'   INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  'flock_id'  INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  'branch_id' INT(11) NULL ,
  'bird_tag'  VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
...
  CONSTRAINT 'fk_bird_flock'
    FOREIGN KEY ('flock_id' )
    REFERENCES 'FLOCK' ('flock_id' )
  CONSTRAINT 'fk_bird_branch'
    FOREIGN KEY ('branch_id' )
    REFERENCES 'BRANCH' ('branch_id' )
 )
```

I want to load each of the tables with a bulk type load (either a multi-insert statement  or LOAD DATA INFILE) from a C++ application.

What is the best way to retrieve the database assigned auto_increment values to use as foreign keys for each of the subsequent table loads.

Note that tables cannot necessarily be loaded in a cascading fashion (i.e. BIRDS will be loaded after FLOCKS and not directly after BRANCHES so "LAST_INSERT_ID" would not be useful when loading BIRDS with respect to BRANCHES).

Each of the tables has candidate natural keys but I am trying to avoid using them as primary or foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

When you use LOAD DATA INFILE (or other multi-row INSERT like INSERT...SELECT), the subsequent call to LAST_INSERT_ID() returns only the *first* id value generated.  But InnoDB allocates id's as a contiguous block, so if you inserted 1000 rows, and LAST_INSERT_ID() reports 1234, then you know that the data load used id's 1234 through 2233.

(Assuming auto_incrment_increment = 1; if not, it's more accurate to say that your data load will use the next 1000 consecutive id's.)

But if you then bulk-load branches after trees, you have the problem of not knowing which tree each branch belongs to.  Some trees may have just one branch, others have six, etc.  Just because you have 1000 trees and 1000 branches, you can't necessarily assume an even distribution.  Then it gets even more complex if you have birds on branches, etc.

Ultimately, bulk-loading data into multiple tables and retaining all the corresponding generated id's is not practical.  You really have to write code to loop over all the input files line by line yourself, and capture LAST_INSERT_ID() row by row to be used in dependent rows.  I haven't found any better solution.

For the more complex case where birds have foreign keys to both their respective branch and their flock, you can try to keep track of the insert id for each branch, and map that to the natural key, but perhaps there are so many branches that it becomes impractical to keep that mapping in memory.  At a certain scale, you find that you can choose to insert birds as you insert *either* branches or flocks, but not both (because there's a many-to-many relationship between branches and flocks, and you can't assume they sort nicely).  So inserting birds may involve leaving NULLs for either their branch or their flock, and then you have to fill in the missing data later with UPDATE.

Comment: I was afraid there was not a good solution for this. I was hoping I could load a table, get the IDs back and populate them into the c++ data structures they originated from before creating the load for the next table.